# Custom runtime image for Alpine

Tags: java, docker, alpine-linux, jlink

I'm trying to create a custom runtime image using the [The Badass Runtime Plugin](https://badass-runtime-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/) and then execute it on Alpine. But it fails with the following error message.

```
jibcmd_1  | /bin/sh: exec: line 1: ./bin/jibcmd: not found
```

If I do something like `docker run -it jibcmd_jibcmd ls -l /app/bin/jibcmd` there's no doubt that the file is there.

If I change my parent image from Alpine to Debian everything works. But I'd like to use Alpine.

Below is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.61'
    id 'application'
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "5.2.0"
    id "org.beryx.runtime" version "1.8.0"
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation "com.github.ajalt:clikt:2.3.0"
    implementation "com.google.cloud.tools:jib-core:0.12.0"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.4.0-b180830.0438'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:2.3.2'
}

runtime {
    modules = ['java.logging', 'java.desktop', 'java.compiler', 'java.xml']
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:14-jdk-buster AS builder
WORKDIR /src

COPY *.gradle *.properties gradlew ./
COPY gradle gradle
RUN ./gradlew --version

COPY . .
RUN ./gradlew jpackageImage

FROM alpine
#FROM debian
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /src/build/jpackage/jibcmd .
CMD exec ./bin/jibcmd
```

Any suggestions regarding how to get this to run on Alpine?

*Update*

```
$ docker run -it jibcmd_jibcmd sh
/app # ldd /app/bin/jibcmd
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f0f4ba6a000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f0f4ba6a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f0f4ba6a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f0f4ba6a000)
Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /app/bin/jibcmd)
/app # ls -l /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
ls: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
/app # apk add libc6-compat
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/1) Installing libc6-compat (1.1.24-r2)
OK: 6 MiB in 15 packages
/app # ls -l /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            26 Apr  6 13:05 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1
/app # ldd /app/bin/jibcmd
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f62a8afa000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f62a8afa000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f62a8afa000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f62a8afa000)
Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /app/bin/jibcmd)
```

ldd still claim that ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is missing...

Comment: What are the permissions on `/app/bin/jibcmd`? What sort of file is it (binary executable, shell script, etc)?

Comment: If it's a binary, does it have shared-library dependencies that are missing?  (`docker run --rm yourimage ldd ./bin/jcmd`)

Comment: @Phil, -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        221888 Apr  6 05:48 bin/jibcmd

Comment: @DavidMaze - That got me a bit further. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by using an Alpine image with Glibc

Comment: which ones have glibc?

Comment: frolvlad/alpine-glibc is one